# Encrypting url(parameters only)

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

In one of projects i got recently have all the urls like

**www.abc.com/controller/action/1222**

I want to encrypt the url parameters only to achieve something like

**www.abc.com/controller/action/saddsadad232dsdfo99jjdf**

I know I can do it by changing all the urls one by one and sending the encrypted parameters and dealing with them all over the places in the project.

**So my question is Is there a way I can encrypt all the urls at once without making changes to every link one by one ?**

Just need a direction.I guess I put all the details needed.

thanks !

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want to avoid to make changes in all the html files where the links with parameters are used !

Comment: No, why do you want encrypt the parameters?

Comment: Because this is a job and i need it done ..silly question though

Comment: I'm trying to help you.  The problem you think you are solving probably isn't getting solved.  But whatever.

Comment: Please let me know if I missed something in the question..

Comment: What are you trying to protect yourself from?  What is your threat model?  Why do you want them to be encrypted?

Comment: Can't you just write a script that will find all urls in the project end encrypt them?

Comment: @LukePark okay here is the problem...suppose there is a url with parameter 1 that assigns a program to a user... suppose someone changed it to 2 , it will assign the program no 2 to that user...this is the problem.....now to solve it one must use the conditions like if else to make sure changing parameters in urls odesn't work ... the project i am working is from another developer... and i cannot add the conditions everywhere in the project so i was thinking of changing the url parameters (encrypted) .. so changing parameter wont help.

Comment: @LukePark and this programs is just one problem there are more like this...

Comment: You're solving the problem in the complete wrong way. Next time you should ask about the problem, not what you THINK is the way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution if you use the `site_url` helper function and you are sure that all your URLs comply this format `www.abc.com/controller/action/1222`:

All you need is to override the `site_url` method of the `CI_Config` class

```
class MY_Config extends CI_Config
{

    public function site_url($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
    {
        $urlPath = ltrim(parse_url($this->_uri_string($uri), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
        $segments = explode('/', $urlPath);
        $numOfSegments = count($segments);
        $result = [$segments[0], $segments[1]]; // controller and action

        // start from the third segment
        for($i = 2; $i < $numOfSegments; $i++)
        {
            // replace md5 with your encoding function
            $result[] = md5($segments[$i]);
        }

        return parent::site_url($result, $protocol);
    }

}
```

Example:

`echo site_url('controller/action/1222');` will output`www.abc.com/controller/action/3a029f04d76d32e79367c4b3255dda4d`

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Hashids helper](https://github.com/sekati/codeigniter-hashids). I think this will do what you're after.

You can pass parameters to your functions like this:

`base_url('account/profile/' . hashids_encrypt($this->user->id))`

You can then decrypt it within the function and use it however you want:

`$id = hashids_decrypt($id);`

Comment: thanks for your answer but ..... by using this i will have to change every url and I am not looking for that.